# Why does scratching a blackboard gives such a painful noise?

Tags: acoustics, resonance, perception

I think we all have heard that terrible sound coming from scratching a blackboard with your nails. How is it produced? Has it something to do with the length of our nails?

Comment: Even wikipedia has an article about that (and it has little to do with physics): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalkboard_scraping

Comment: Our brains interpret the sound in a way that triggers the negative sensation.

Comment: I am flagging to report this question as "gives me the heebie jeebies just thinking about it thanks a bunch"

Comment: I think it must have sonething to do with the fingernails making small "jumps" on the surface as they are dragged upon it and hence causing a vibration...

Comment: Actually, like I realise now, you can divide the question up in two parts: a physical part, wich would explain the origins of the sound (and I think valerio92 comes very close to answering that question), and a psychological part wich is why it is so annoying to us. I think the second part is the hardest to answer.

Comment: @CountIblis That´s obvious as it can be! But why is it thís sound triggers a negative sensation, while music triggers a positive sensation (even to those who like The Sex Pistols the positive sensation is triggered while many people describe the music as an attack on the ear)?